# Live HTML Previewer extension issue

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am try to use Live HTML Previewer in VS code but it gives me the following error message:

> Running the contributed command: 'extension.sidePreview' failed.

I tried all the extensions but they all didn't work too.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/68233569/836330 for info about the vscode team's Live Preview extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [Live Server](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ritwickdey.LiveServer) by Ritwick Dey

Answer (score 2):

Try Html preview extension from Thomas Hakoon Townsend (tht13.html-preview-vscode), not live HTML preview, that extension doesn't work in ubuntu and others.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix the issue by reverting to a previous version of the extension. Although someone else reported success with upgrading to the latest version, this approach did not work for me. Therefore, I suggest trying to downgrade the extension. To assist with this process, I created a brief video tutorial that demonstrates the steps required, which you can find on YouTube.

https://youtu.be/2urVx2YVRxY